# how to get notification when user change checkbox in yii

Tags: checkbox, yii

I am new to web development, using Yii to develop a web site, and run into a problem. I have a bunch of checkbox populated dynamic.

I want to get notification on server side when user change the checkbox status(select or deselect) . How can I achieve that?

Comment: There are a million and one ways to accomplish this. The easiest is to mail yourself using PHPs [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function

Comment: Are you kidding me? [Learn how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) if you want real help

Answer (score 3):

By serverside, I presume you are wanting to send the change event to the server for processing and maybe even then send a result back to the client.

This is called AJAX and you can set it up in javascript/jQuery using the onChange event.

You can code this in Yii when you render the checkboc, for example

```
echo CHtml::activeCheckbox($model,'fieldname',array('onchange'=>'js: some javascript in here;');
```

Your javascript will probably then call a jQuery ajax request to post or get data to the server and then in the same ajax request you can process any results sent back ...

See the Yii wiki for more details and here's a good place to start:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/394/javascript-and-ajax-with-yii/

btw: the Yii wiki is packed full of useful tutorials and articles.

Comment: I can get a notification when the checkbox changes, but I still do not figure out how to pass the value of the checkbox to server. Can someone give a simple code snippet for that?

Comment: I get this worked, here is the simple code<script type="text/javascript">
function submitOption() {

   var url = "http://localhost/new/test/index.php?r=option";
   $.post(url, $("#jingcai_bid").serialize());
}
</script>

Comment: @user1450627, why don't you check this answer up?